# How does a developer set the visibility of multiple app icons in OS X Launchpad.app?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, icons

The question is primarily applicable to third-party Mac software which contain multiple applications such as helpers or uninstall items. This is aside from one or more individual app files that may or may also not be displayed. Some of the shown do not seem to match the intended use for the Launchpad.app because they should not be visible to the user in that context.

For example, Adobe CC installs and shows a folder named "Adobe Application Manager (Other)" that contains "AAMLauncherUtil.app". The extension is hidden in the Launchpad.app view. The actual location appears to be /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Application Manager/core/.

This does not apply to apps submitted to the Mac App Store. One simple reason I suspect is that the Mac App Store will only allow a single app binary submitted.

I have note been able to find any reference to Launchpad.app or developers preparing their programs specifically for Launchpad visibility in OS X developer documentation. Every other search for this question returns related question for end-users trying to organize and hide their own apps. Some of the answers to these questions are related to desktoppicture.db and modifying it's contents.